# how do i find the toal orders in this format

Tags: javascript, node.js

i am getting an output

```
[] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [ { order_status: 'Received' } ] [{ order_status: '1' },{ order_status: '1'},{ order_status: 'Accepted'}] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [ { order_status: 'Received' } ] [] [ { order_status: 'Accepted' } ] []
```

I need to find the total order, if it has an empty array, display 0 else display number of objects. This is my final output i need.

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `Array#map` and get the length of each array.

```js
let arr = [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [ { order_status: 'Received' } ], [{ order_status: '1' },{ order_status: '1'},{ order_status: 'Accepted'}], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [ { order_status: 'Received' } ], [], [ { order_status: 'Accepted' } ], [] ];
let res = arr.map(x => x.length);
console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
```

Comment: Upvoted but maybe change from `let` to `const` since you're not mutating the variables

Comment: Maybe use `.join(" ")` to make it in the same format as the OP wanted.

Comment: I'm getting individual output instead of an array

Comment: @PrajwalKRao Don't call `JSON.stringify` to just get an array. You might want to call `res.join(" ")`

Comment: i am getting an output like this [ 0 ]
[ 0 ]
[ 0 ]
[ 0 ]
[ 0 ]
[ 0 ]
[ 0 ]
[ 0 ]
[ 3 ]
[ 1 ]
[ 1 ]
[ 0 ]
[ 0 ]
[ 0 ]
[ 0 ]
[ 0 ]
[ 0 ]
[ 0 ]
[ 0 ]
[ 0 ]
[ 1 ]
[ 0 ]
[ 0 ]
[ 0 ]

Comment: @PrajwalKRao Use `console.log(res.join(" "))` then.

Comment: this gives output in string but i need in number

Comment: @PrajwalKRao What exactly do you need? `res` is already an array of numbers. Just access it.

Comment: yes but it is an array of numbers i nedd ouput like [i am getting an output like this

[0 ,0,0 ,0, 0 ,0 ,0, 0 ,0 ,0, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0 ,0 ,0 ,0, 0, 0, 1 ,0, 1, 0]

Comment: @PrajwalKRao What output do you want? `res.join(" ")` gives you `0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0` (like specified in your question).